# Java converter from kml/shapefile to Geojson

Tags: kml, geojson

I would like to write a command line program using Java that take in KML/Shapfile and output GeoJSON file. 
What I usually did is go over ogre2ogre and manually convert my file.
Once I got the GeoJson I modified the content of it a little bit before output final GeoJSON.

I would like to skip the manual part and find some API that do the conversion for me.

Anyone could help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) provides a KML+GeoJSON toolkit, with both a KML parser/writer and a GeoJSON parser/writer, all in Java. 
So this allows to read KML content, and write it as GeoJSON.

You can test this conversion using the demo app [OSMNavigator](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/OSMNavigator).

It is targeting Android, so for your need you would have to pick the relevant classes, and remove code sections you don't need (icon loading, overlay building, Parcelable implementation, for instance).

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what i need. Thanks